# What is the best efficient way I use twitter Icon in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-widget

> Using the library `font_awesome_flutter`, we know can find most social media logos.
> Among them, we got the twitter logo below this line.

```
FontAwesomeIcons.twitter;
```

```
FontAwesomeIcons.twitterSquare;
```

I forget mentioned these line.
After adding anyone, we should do this also run in our terminal

```
 pub clean
```

And then

```
pub get update
```

Comment: Maybe you can search alternatives here : https://fontawesome.com/v5/search?q=twitter&o=r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

```
       const Icon(
          FontAwesomeIcons.twitter,
          size: 30,
        ),
        const Icon(
          FontAwesomeIcons.squareTwitter,
          size: 30,
        ),
```

Result-> [image]

Comment: Try to accept or mark my answer

Comment: I apologize for the late. Thanks, man.

Answer (score 2):

It should be in `Icon()` widget for it to work

```
...
child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.twitter, color: Colors.blue,)
..
```